# How to implement High pass and low pass filtering using dygraphs?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, dygraphs

I am working on a project of dygraphs and I need add functionalities like HPF and LPF.I have seen that "d3.js" has inbuilt functionalities for LPF and HPF. Is there any way to perform this task in dygraphs?

Answer (score 0):

I got it..We can set the range of y-axis with the help of valueRange() property.